# Sling servlet bypass to default servlet

Tags: apache-felix, sling

how can I bypass or forward the request captured in a sling servlet to the default one?

I want to do a custom process for all GET requests, but for some specific ones, let the default servlet do the job.

I'm stuck with 
"javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(????)" but I don't know how to continue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more context around your exact need?  Based on this information it sounds like you actually want a Filter and not a custom Servlet.  In what cases is your custom Servlet needed / not needed and in general what is your custom servlet doing that the OOB GET servlet is not?